# Save current data

Tags: save, monitoring

I'd like to write the current data, but the Monitor and PutAppend are being written in such a way that the function **pot** does not match the current variables **(a and b)**. How can I fix this?

````
f[a_, b_] = Exp[-Sqrt[b*x + Cos[c]]] + a*y;

PP[a_, b_] := NIntegrate[f[a, b], {c, 0, 2*Pi}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];

P = Monitor[Table[{{a, b}, pot = PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}], {{" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", pot}, 
   PutAppend[{" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", pot}, "C:/Users/Public/P1.txt"]}]

```
````

Comment: You must put the "PutAppend" inside the "Table" function, not inside "Monitor"

Comment: Could you write, How do it?

Comment: Monitor[ Table[PutAppend[...]; {{a, b}, pot = PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}] {}]] , ...]

Comment: I rewrote code as you showed `P = Monitor[
  Table[PutAppend[{" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", pot}, "C:/Users/Public/P1.txt"]; {{a, b}, pot = PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}], {" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", pot}]` , but the same problem is observed. Here I wrote result from the file (first 3 lines only): `{" a =", 1, " b =", 1, " p =", pot}
{" a =", 1, " b =", 2, " p =", 3249.790767096823 - 10.724358112221017*I}
{" a =", 1, " b =", 3, " p =", 3202.877038820512 - 5.362166501734869*I}
` Instead of **pot** in the line 1 must be value of the function from the line 2, etc.

Comment: Here is the command: `P = Monitor[
  Table[PutAppend[{" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", pot}, 
    "d:/tmp/P1.txt"]; {{a, b}, pot = PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 
    5, 1}], {{" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", pot}}]`  There are some problems with Integrate, but the first lines in the file are: `{" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", pot}
{" a =", a, " b =", b, " p =", NIntegrate[f[a, b], {c, 0, 2*Pi}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  {y, 0, 10}]}`

Comment: An after thought. Maybe it is a version problem. I am using 13.1. In this case you may try Sow and Reap and write the  file at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want or expect:

```mathematica
f[a_, b_] = Exp[-Sqrt[b*x + Cos[c]]] + a*y;

PP[a_, b_] := 
  NIntegrate[f[a, b], {c, 0, 2*Pi}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];

P = Monitor[
  Table[{{a, b}, pot = PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}], 
  Block[{t = {" a =", a, ", b =", b, ", p =", pot}}, 
   PutAppend[t, $HomeDirectory <> "/res.txt"]; Row[t]]]
```

Here is the content of "~/res.txt":

```
{" a =", a, ", b =", b, ", p =", 15733.879349760984 - 2.145440037693274*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 15733.879349760984 - 2.145440037693274*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 3249.790767096823 - 10.724358112221017*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 3202.877038820512 - 5.362166501734868*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 4, ", p =", 3183.937399330214 - 3.57481638498084*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 3173.790549970787 - 2.6811485163890296*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 3167.508922680442 - 2.1448452737137247*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 6391.383475713819 - 10.72409070610717*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 6344.46943020684 - 5.362301511961679*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 4, ", p =", 6325.529936985096 - 3.574883938206328*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 6315.383021309188 - 2.68124962394431*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 6309.10186657632 - 2.1450031600995176*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 9532.975956862454 - 10.724109305642521*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 9486.06158392852 - 5.362532735309611*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 4, ", p =", 9467.122816411187 - 3.5750207147100945*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 9450.693876792158 - 2.1452134608202007*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 12674.568734289138 - 10.724141302098825*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 12627.654082202764 - 5.362121831983023*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 12598.56799949393 - 2.6810289453789338*I}
{" a =", 5, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 12592.285982889785 - 2.1452539452330837*I}
{" a =", 5, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 15769.246849625648 - 5.362180691001058*I}
{" a =", 5, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 15740.16033978343 - 2.6810083710060937*I}
{" a =", a, ", b =", b, ", p =", 15733.879349760984 - 2.145440037693274*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 15733.879349760984 - 2.145440037693274*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 3249.790767096823 - 10.724358112221017*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 3202.877038820512 - 5.362166501734868*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 4, ", p =", 3183.937399330214 - 3.57481638498084*I}
{" a =", 1, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 3173.790549970787 - 2.6811485163890296*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 3167.508922680442 - 2.1448452737137247*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 6391.383475713819 - 10.72409070610717*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 6344.46943020684 - 5.362301511961679*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 4, ", p =", 6325.529936985096 - 3.574883938206328*I}
{" a =", 2, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 6315.383021309188 - 2.68124962394431*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 6309.10186657632 - 2.1450031600995176*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 9532.975956862454 - 10.724109305642521*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 9486.06158392852 - 5.362532735309611*I}
{" a =", 3, ", b =", 4, ", p =", 9467.122816411187 - 3.5750207147100945*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 9450.693876792158 - 2.1452134608202007*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 12674.568734289138 - 10.724141302098825*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 12627.654082202764 - 5.362121831983023*I}
{" a =", 4, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 12598.56799949393 - 2.6810289453789338*I}
{" a =", 5, ", b =", 1, ", p =", 12592.285982889785 - 2.1452539452330837*I}
{" a =", 5, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 15769.246849625648 - 5.362180691001058*I}
{" a =", 5, ", b =", 5, ", p =", 15740.16033978343 - 2.6810083710060937*I}
```

Comment: It does not match. For `a=1, b=1` it should be `3249.79 - 10.7244 I` and not `15733.879349760984 - 2.145440037693274*I`

Comment: Maybe because I run that multiple times. Should be better (more consistent) now...

Comment: It's not what I would like write in the file. In first line Mathematica puts function value (number), while the arguments are letters, i.e. the function must also be of type string. `{" a =", a, ", b =", b, ", p =", 15733.879349760984 - 2.145440037693274*I}`

Comment: @MamMam Change `t` to have the form you want. If you do not know how to do that, please provide more explanations in your question.

Comment: I run your code and get the following data from the file (5 first line from the file):
`{" a =", a, ", b =", b, ", p =", pot} {" a =", 1, ", b =", 1, ", p =", pot} {" a =", 1, ", b =", 2, ", p =", 3249.790767096823 - 10.724358112221017*I} {" a =", 1, ", b =", 3, ", p =", 3202.877038820512 - 5.362166501734869*I} {" a =", 1, ", b =", 4, ", p =", 3183.937399330214 - 3.574816384980839*I}`
First line is correct, but second and follow lines not correct, because the value of the function corresponding to the values of the arguments from the second line is in the third line, etc.

Comment: Could you help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to make it match. It seems the issue due to the assignment inside the table and some race condition.

```
f[a_, b_] := Exp[-Sqrt[b*x + Cos[c]]] + a*y;

PP[a_, b_] := NIntegrate[f[a, b], {c, 0, 2*Pi}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];

data = Reap@Monitor[Table[pot = {{a, b}, PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}], 
    Sow@{" a =", pot[[1, 1]], " b =", pot[[1, 2]], " p =", pot[[2]]}];
```

Now compare the table data with the monitor collected data, they are the same now

```
 actualData = data[[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 monitorData = (First@data[[2]])[[2 ;;]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So instead of doing as you did which is

```
Table[ {{a, b}, pot = PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Changed it

```
 Table[pot = {{a, b}, PP[a, b]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}]
```

I did not bother writing it to the file, since that is not important. I just wanted to verify that the monitor collected data is the same as generated by the `Table` command.

I also think it is better not to write to disk inside the Monitor. Simply collect the data first (as the above), and later on, you can write the data all at once to the file.  Should be more efficient also.

Comment: I would like to write current data to the file, because a calculation what I do run very long and I want analyze obtained data in parallel with calculations.

Comment: Could you help me with this

Comment: @MamMam  But I have given you the solution above? The above now generates the same data from Monitor as from Table? All what you have to do it write it to the file as you were doing before yourself. Did you try to do that? i.e. use your `PutAppend` but with the corrected code in place instead.